# Trouble installing 21.10, freezes during install

Tags: boot, freeze, 21.10

I am and have been attempting to install ubuntu 21.10 for the pass few days with no success at all. anytime I attempt to install it, it loads seems likes its working but I never make it to the liveusb version (I think thats what its called when its like the trial before installing fully). I have tired adding the "nomodeset" thing to the grub editing stuff, it didn't help out at all.
I am using a AMD acer aspire 3 laptop, lmk if i need to include anything else

Comment: does the liveusb work on a different computer?  maybe try it on a friends computer.  Sounds like its a bad liveusb, perhaps the original image is corrupt or maybe when it wrote to the USB there was a problem.  Could also be a bad USB drive.  I used to use dd to make my live usb then one time it didn't work, now I use etcher or rufus to make my liveusb.

Comment: @MichaelMantion nevermind, i thought it had worked but it didnt, it did work on the other laptop i had around thought so the USB is fine, it just wont load for the laptop I regularly use, i used Rufus to make my liveusbs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that was resolved by enabling SGX in Bios. Try it out and let me know :)